# Need help to redirect my one JSP page with prepopulated value in my textbox in another JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I am trying to redirect my one JSP page with prepopulated value in my textbox in another JSP. Want to populate whole column data in the 2nd JSP after I click the specific link associated with ${tempEvents.eventName}

**1st JSP Code:**

```
<table id="table" align="center">
<c:forEach var="tempEvents" items="${events}">
<tr>
  <td align="center">
    <a href = "specificEvent" id ="linkId">${tempEvents.eventName}</a>
  </td>
 </tr>              
 </c:forEach>
 </table>
```

**2nd JSP:**

```
  <form action = "specificEventMethod" modelAttribute="event">
  <table id="table" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>Event Name: </td>
    <td align="center">${event.eventName}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Event Date: </td>
    <td align="center">${event.eventDate}</td>
   <!-- <td><input type = "text" name = "event.eventDate" disabled/></td> -->
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Fund Collected: </td>
   <td><input type = "text" name = "event.fundCollected" disabled/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fund Used: </td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "fundUsed"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Remaining Balance: </td>
   <td><input type = "text" name = "remainingBalance" disabled/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center"><input class="btn btn-default custom" type = "submit" value = "Save"/></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value via url by building the anchor's href as -

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/Demo/2ndJSPPage?eventName="${tempEvents.eventName} />
```

Then in 2nd jsp page get it as -

```
<p><%= request.getParameter("eventName") %></p>
```